# How to change z-index on svg files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I know there are plenty of these questions and I've already seen them ,but none helped me in this case.

I'm working on React Application. And one component is one SVG file and second component is second SVG file.

Both of these components I'm rendering inside main file (App.js). Just like this.

```
<div className="app">
  <div className="container">
  <Gender 
    changeGender={changeGender}/>

  <Range 
    getHeight={getHeight}
    getWeight={getWeight} 
    Height={bmi.height}
    Weight={bmi.weight}/>

  <Button className="button" />
  </div>

  <Waves className="waves" />
  

  <Result />
</div>
```

**Waves** component is the component that I want it to be on the bottom and **Button** component is the component that I want to be on the top. For better understanding ,here is the picture.

[image]

**Waves component** is simply SVG file which I'm importing like this :

```
import {ReactComponent as Waves} from './Icons/waves.svg';
```

And **Button component** looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Arrow } from "../Icons/arrow.svg";

function Button(){

    return(
        <div className="buttonContainer">
            <Arrow className="arrow-icon" />
        </div>   
    );
}

export default Button;
```

I've tried to set z-indexes for both but nothing changes. Do you have any idea how is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: swap the order of button and waves. SVG draws in painter's order i.e. what comes second is painted over what comes first.

Comment: z-index doesn't work in svg. If you want a svg shape to be on top of the others you draw that shape last

Answer (score 2):

Z-Index doesn't work for SVG files. If you want SVG shape to be on top of the others ,render that shape as last. Last shape rendered will be on the top of the others.

Comment: Consider explicitly mentioning that "render that shape as last" and "be on the top of the others" involves modification the DOM (the "order" of the DOM)